# Best Practice: SQL Queries in a Loop

Tags: c#

Is there a best practice around executing SQL queries in a Loop? I'm looking for supporting argument for or against.

The Negative as I understand it is:

- The expensive nature of opening and closing the connection every x
  times.
- Possible table lock and holding up of loop
- Timing issue as mentioned below in comment

Comment: The best practice by far is "don't do it". Even if you open the connection once, and keep it open throughout your loop, the round-trips are going to kill your timing. Go out of your way to construct a super-clever SQL that gets you everything at once. This would push your loop onto the server side, avoiding network round-trips.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight so if there is an important "update" that needs to happen in the super-clever SQL, a check would need to be done in SQL itself to ensure the record updated. Is that correct? It does make for a maintenance nightmare, and a large amount of effort put into the SQL.

Comment: Maybe if we understood the problem you are trying to solve we could suggest alternatives.

Comment: There are many elements to your scenario that could change the advice you are seeking. Can you give a more specific example?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that requires multiple round trips to the server?

Comment: What is your problem statement?

Comment: The problem is understanding whether it is efficient to implement DB queries in a loop. Some people don't care and most of the code I see considers this irrelevant. I'm trying to understand the reasons for best practice - no point holding or implementing a standard if you don't UNDERSTAND IT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience, sql query inside a loop is not advisable. Just like @dasblinkenlight was said **DON'T DO IT**. It will consume too much memory and resources and it will take **too much** time especially when you have a **BIG** database.

[Take a look at here](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2010/10/07/optimizing-sql-removing-queries-inside-loops/) 
 
Try to use **INNER JOIN**